# Using NOT LIKE and OR statement together producing FALSE output

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am having issues with my SQL statement below.  The `NOT LIKE` and `OR` statement is producing `FALSE` statements, in that it is producing the output when it should not, since I am using a `NOT LIKE`. When I put the statement as a stand-alone (*without* the `OR` condition), it works as intended.

For example, I am still seeing 'automation' in my `ld.lead_name` column.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  I can't figure out why this is not working...

SQL Statement

```
SELECT
    ld.status,
    ld.lead_name
FROM
    DATAWAREHOUSE.SFDC_STAGING.SFDC_LEAD AS ld
WHERE
    ld.status <> 'Open'
    AND (
        ld.lead_name NOT LIKE '%test%'
        OR ld.lead_name NOT LIKE '%t3st%'
        OR ld.lead_name NOT LIKE '%auto%'
        OR ld.lead_name NOT LIKE '%autoXmation%'
        OR ld.lead_name NOT LIKE 'automation%'
    )
    ;
```

Comment: Don't you want to use `AND` rather than `OR` here?

Comment: This would always result being true except for those where you have all those test, t3st ... together. Try replacing the ORs wıith AND. Alternatively you can remove all those NOTs and put one outside the parentheses. AND NOT (.... OR .... OR....).

Comment: I suggest you read up on the way these logic test operators will work. If you think it through as you read it ... You hit the first `OR` and the value is `%t3st%`. Well, that value is not `%test%` so it is `TRUE` and stops. Whereas if it was `AND` it would have checked all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use `AND` instead of `OR`:

```
SELECT
    ld.status,
    ld.lead_name
FROM
    DATAWAREHOUSE.SFDC_STAGING.SFDC_LEAD AS ld
WHERE
    ld.status <> 'Open'
    AND ld.lead_name NOT LIKE '%test%'
    AND ld.lead_name NOT LIKE '%t3st%'
    AND ld.lead_name NOT LIKE '%auto%'
    AND ld.lead_name NOT LIKE '%autoXmation%'
    AND ld.lead_name NOT LIKE 'automation%';
```